# SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing a problem with my slow improvement in SQL Server 2008 R2 and here is the case:

I want to create a stored procedure that accepts parameters, but I want it to work in a special way so that if I pass 2 parameters in search in a table patient for example where as if I pass to it one parameter I want it to search in a table school and so on.

Any help will be really appreciated

Thank you

```
USE []
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[proc_search_patient_ByID]    Script Date: 11/28/2014     07:47:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_search_patient_ByID]
( 
@PatID_pk int ,
@Cntid  smallint,
@FamID int
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
select  cntid AS Center , PatFName AS FirstName   , PatMName AS MiddleName , PatLName AS LastName   , PatMother AS MotherName   ,PatDOB AS DOB
from tbl 
where Cntid=@Cntid  and PatId_PK = @PatID_pk
```

i want my procedure to work in this way if i supply 2 param but if i supply @FamID i want it to search in completely another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing null value for unused parameters and inside the stored procedure put a check for nulls to switch tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_search_patient_ByID]
( 
@PatID_pk int ,
@Cntid  smallint,
@FamID int
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF @Cntid IS NULL
BEGIN
   --Use select stmt of a table
END
ELSE
   --Use select stmt of another table
BEGIN
END
```

Likewise switch tables with appropriate parameters.